# MSVC 2015 optimizes out volatile variables?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, side-effects

I have the following code compiled in MSVS2015 in release mode:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"

void f()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        volatile int var = 10;
        if (var) // Breakpoint can't be set
        {
            printf("Test\n"); // Breakpoint can't be set
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    f();
    return 0; // Second breakpoint
}
```

I was thinking that `volatile` keyword doesn't allow the compiler to optimize variable, but since I can't set breakpoint I can't check the variable's value and it looks like totally optimized.

Do I have incorrect understanding of `volatile` and side effects?

**UPDATE**

```
MSVS Version : 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
```

Disassembly (Release):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"


void f()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        volatile int var = 10;
        if (var)
        {
            printf("Test\n");
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
00FE1040  push        ebp  
00FE1041  mov         ebp,esp  
00FE1043  push        ecx  
00FE1044  push        esi  
    f();
00FE1045  mov         esi,0Ah  
00FE104A  nop         word ptr [eax+eax]  
00FE1050  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],0Ah  
00FE1057  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-4],0  
00FE105B  je          main+2Ah (0FE106Ah)  
00FE105D  push        offset string "Test\n" (0FE20F8h)  
00FE1062  call        printf (0FE1010h)  
00FE1067  add         esp,4  
00FE106A  sub         esi,1  
00FE106D  jne         main+10h (0FE1050h)  
    return 0;
00FE106F  xor         eax,eax  
00FE1071  pop         esi  
}
00FE1072  mov         esp,ebp  
00FE1074  pop         ebp  
00FE1075  ret
```

Comment: The question is if the line `if (var)` generates a read instruction or not. If not, the compiler is hopelessly broken and non-conforming. Which everyone already knows is the case with VS.

Comment: Are you sure it is at all possible to set breakpoints in release builds?

Comment: if possible, disassemble the code. Only way to tell.

Comment: Strange! In Disassemby, Code is generated for function `f()` in debug mode but in release mode, No code at all!

Comment: From my experience, MS compiler doesn't remove `volatile` accesses like that for global and `static` variables. So, for a workaround, just add `static` to the definition of `var`.

Comment: `var` is volatile but doesn't have external linkage and the address is never taken. Standards-compliant or not I don't know, but in the Windows ABI the compiler is correct to deduce that the value can never change.

Comment: @Ben In accordance to disassembly variable is not optimized so the issue doesn't seem to be in generated code.